# Android, loading multiple ImageViews (using UIL) inside a Fragment -> Grow heap

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, universal-image-loader

I'm using a NavigationDrawer to navigate through my app, at the moment the Drawer contains a single Fragment which has a ListView ( with around 50 rows ). When pressed, each row displays a ViewPager with 4 Tabs ( each of them contains 4 ImageViews and some text ). Now here's the problem: when I swipe from a Tab to another, Grow Heap error shows up in the logcat:

```
04-12 12:53:25.810    9377-9377/com.mypd.wiki I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 13.650MB for 600016-byte allocation
04-12 12:53:25.850    9377-9377/com.mypd.wiki I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 15.937MB for 2400016-byte allocation
04-12 12:53:26.130    9377-9377/com.mypd.wiki I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 18.507MB for 1960016-byte allocation
04-12 12:53:30.865    9377-9651/com.mypd.wiki I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 19.175MB for 557584-byte allocation
04-12 12:53:31.470    9377-9439/com.mypd.wiki I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 19.693MB for 557584-byte allocation
04-12 12:53:32.305    9377-9439/com.mypd.wiki I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 20.348MB for 557584-byte allocation
04-12 12:53:34.225    9377-9441/com.mypd.wiki I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 21.794MB for 278800-byte allocation
04-12 12:53:41.455    9377-9441/com.mypd.wiki I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 23.446MB for 557584-byte allocation
04-12 12:53:44.650    9377-9651/com.mypd.wiki I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 24.002MB for 557584-byte allocation
```

ListView listener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("id", position);
                TabStripAdapter newFragment = new TabStripAdapter();
                newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

The ViewPager along with the Adapter:

```
public class TabStripAdapter extends Fragment {
    CollectionPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.models_list_adapter, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapterViewPager = new CollectionPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }

    public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();

        public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 4;
        }
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            registeredFragments.remove(position);
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
                    Tab1 frag1 = new Tab1().newInstance();
                    frag1.setArguments(bundle);
                    return frag1;
                case 1:
                    Bundle bundle1 = getArguments();
                    Tab2 frag2 = new Tab2().newInstance();
                    frag2.setArguments(bundle1);
                    return frag2;
                case 2:
                    Bundle bundle2 = getArguments();
                    Tab3 frag3 = new Tab3().newInstance();
                    frag3.setArguments(bundle2);
                    return frag3;
                case 3:
                    Bundle bundle3 = getArguments();
                    Tab4 frag4 = new Tab4().newInstance();
                    frag4.setArguments(bundle3);
                    return frag4;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Tab1";
                case 1:
                    return "Tab2";
                case 2:
                    return "Tab3";
                case 3:
                    return "Tab4";

                default:
                    return "None";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how one of my tabs looks like:

```
    public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
        DisplayImageOptions options;
        ImageView extraImg1;
        ImageView extraImg2;
        ImageView extraImg3;
        ImageView extraImg4;

        public Tab1 newInstance() {
            return new Tab1();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading_audi)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .delayBeforeLoading(200)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_strip_1, container, false);
            // Bundle setup:
            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            int position = bundle.getInt("id");

            if(bundle.containsKey("id")){

                position = bundle.getInt("id");
            } else {
                this.getActivity().finish();
            }

            // TextView setup:
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText("Tab1 design");
            TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab1);
            description.setText(Data.Tab1[position]);

            // ImageView setup:
            extraImg1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.extraImg1);
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Data.TabA[position], extraImg1, options);
            //
            extraImg2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.extraImg2);
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Data.TabB[position], extraImg2, options);
            //
            extraImg3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.extraImg3);
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Data.TabC[position], extraImg3, options);
            //
            extraImg4 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.extraImg4);
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Data.TabD[position], extraImg4, options);

            return view;
        }
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
        }

  // Here I try to recycle the ImageViews but I'm not sure I'm doing it right...

        public static void recycleImagesFromView(View view) {
            if(view instanceof ImageView) {
                Drawable drawable = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable();
                if(drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)
                {
                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)drawable;
                    bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
                }
            }

            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    recycleImagesFromView(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            recycleImagesFromView(getView());
        }
    }
```

UIL configuration:

```
public class UILApplication extends Application {       

...

    public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {

        ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context);
        config.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
        config.threadPoolSize(3);
        config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();
        config.memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache());
        config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();
        config.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator());
        config.diskCacheSize(200 * 1024 * 1024); 
        config.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO);
        config.writeDebugLogs(); // Remove for release app

        // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
    }
}
```

My guess is that I'm leaking memory somewhere, either I have to recycle the ImageViews in a proper way, either I'm missing something.

Sorry for my english skills.

Answer (score 0):

in OnCreate() method

```
.cacheInMemory(true)
```

should change to

```
.cacheInMemory(false)
```

Comment: Still getting Grow Heap error, I played yesterday with most of the options provided by UIL.